# Extract portion of netcdf file based on latitude and longitude in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I have a netcdf file of GRACE data containing change in groundwater storage  of all over the world from 2002 to 2016. That also contains lat/lon values
I want to extract data of a particular study area from that world data based upon lat lon values of that area using R .
The latitude variable runs from +90 to -90 and the longitude variable runs form 0 to 360.

I wish to extract a subset of the overall grid using the following geographical corner boundaries.
 bottom left corner :(lat 21.5, loon 85.5)   Top left Corner :(lat 27.5, lon 85.5)     Top right corner :(lat 27.5 lon 89.5)    bottom right corner :(lat 21.5, lon 89.5) .

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But problem is I have to solve this with R not python

Comment: Why not simply use the CDO solution cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 in.nc out.nc ?

Comment: @Adrian Tompkin  can u plz elaborate the cdo solution..actually I am new in programming...

Comment: please see the linked question/answer for full explanation